# Is there an equivalence to CDOSYS AutoGenerateTextBody in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, html, email

I'm porting some VBScript code which generates emails using the standard CDOSYS Message object.  The Message oject has a property `AutoGenerateTextBody` which when true will cause it to automatically create the `TextBody` property value when you assign HTML to the `HTMLBody` property.  Hence creating the typical text/plain and text/html alternatives in the message body.

However .NET appears to be missing this function.  The `MailMessage` object does have the ability to create alternative views but there doesn't appear to be a way to easily create the text body content from the HTML content.

I'm not necessarily looking for an auto-magic option but I do need a solution to taking what is an HTML string and converting it to a reasonable plain text representation.  Just dropping all the HTML markup doesn't cut it.

Is there a tool buried somewhere in the existing .NET framework that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything in the .NET framework itself, but you could use CDO to do the conversion for you. Admittedly it feels like a bit of a dirty hack, but does the job!

Add a reference to the "Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library" (in the COM tab of the "Add Reference" dialog) and away you go:

```
public string GetTextBody(string htmlBody)
{
    CDO.Message msg = new CDO.Message();
    msg.AutoGenerateTextBody = true;
    msg.HTMLBody = htmlBody;

    return msg.TextBody;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks.  ;)  I'd rather write my one HTML->Text conversion than add a dependency on the CDOSYS just achieve this operation.

Comment: @Anthony: Yep, I agree completely. Just thought I'd mention the possibility.